# Join tables - only return first record and distinct column if exist else return null for column

Tags: oracle, join, distinct

Join two tables and return first record of second table - have this code. One of the column in the second table can have the same values. If so, return the value; otherwise, return null.

used distinct but still need to return first record, even though column value is not distinct(i.e. return null)

```
CREATE TABLE Person ("LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"TICKET_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE));
BEGIN
insert into Person(last_name,ticket_number) values('johnson','100');
insert into Person(last_name,ticket_number) values('smith','200');
END;
/

CREATE TABLE Orders 
("REGION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"STATE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"A_CODE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
"STORE_NUM" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"TICKET_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
"SEQ" NUMBER(12));

SELECT a.last_name,
     a.ticket_number,
     b.region,
     b.state,
     b.SEQ1,
     B.A_CODE
FROM person a

BEGIN
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '111', 'FLL', 1);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '222', 'FLL', 2);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '333', 'FLL', 3);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '444', 'FLL', 4);

END;
/


JOIN (SELECT ticket_number, MIN(SEQ) AS SEQ1,
        MIN(region) AS region,
        MIN(state) AS state, MIN(A_CODE) AS A_CODE
 FROM orders WHERE REGION IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY ticket_number) b ON a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number where 
  a.last_name is not null;
```

A_CODE values are the same - return value

```
LAST_NAME   TICKET_NUMBER   REGION  STATE   SEQ1    A_CODE
johnson         100           S       F1      1       FLL
```

However, if A_CODE values are not unique(i.e. not the same), then return null for A_CODE column and still return first record of second table.
note: as an option, the column value does not need to return null if not equal. It can return a literal like 'not equal'

```
LAST_NAME   TICKET_NUMBER   REGION  STATE   SEQ1    A_CODE
johnson      100             S       F1     1         (NULL)
```

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: What does "first" mean? Tables have no order. Result sets (per ORDER BY) have order. Also the rest of your description of what should be returned is not clear. (And you give two return examples, but what was the input example for each one?) Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. [mcve]

Comment: See Vijiy answer..the following is in regards to the second joined table. First means first record in table, since the 2 particular fields values being parsed have equal values for all records - never different. The second condition - if all the values in one specific column are the same(i.e. a unique value), then return that value; otherwise return a simple literal. This one is a little different than the first condition, since the values can either be unique or not unique unlike the first condition where the values are always the same for all the records.

Comment: Once again: Tables have no order, so saying "first record in table" doesn't mean anything, and you have not clarified. Do you say "first" to mean "smallest"? Do you think that ('100', 'S', 'F1', '111', 'FLL', 1) is "first" because it is inserted first? It is not. Rows can come back in any order when queried without an ORDER BY. PS Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: Only one record is required for both conditions - three columns from join/2nd table. Because all the values are equal for two columns(unique for each column) in the 2nd table, then return the values from both columns. Min(seq) gets the first one(seq incrementer), although it could be any row. The 2nd condition also requires returning one record. In this case, the 3rd column in the 2nd table can include either equal or different values. If the values are all equal, return the value; otherwise, return a literal. Post edits?

Comment: I can't make sense of your comment, you are not writing clearly. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. Also you haven't answered my question re "first". (Maybe you mean that the "first row of a group" after GROUP BY is the one with the smallest SEQ value? But you are not clear.) Re edits: Questions & answers here are "posts". Clarifications should be made by editing posts, not by commenting. Posts should be self-contained, and comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below would be the query,

```
SELECT a.last_name,
     a.ticket_number,
     b.region,
     b.state,
     b.SEQ1,
     case when B.MIN_A_CODE = B.MAX_A_CODE then B.MIN_A_CODE else 'NULL' end A_CODE
FROM person a
JOIN ( SELECT ticket_number, MIN(SEQ) AS SEQ1,
        MIN(region) AS region,
        MIN(state) AS state, MIN(A_CODE) AS MIN_A_CODE, max(A_CODE) as MAX_A_CODE
 FROM orders WHERE REGION IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY ticket_number) b ON a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number where 
  a.last_name is not null;
```

I added one more row to table orders.

```
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '111', 'FLL', 1);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '222', 'FLL', 2);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '333', 'FLL', 3);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '444', 'FLL', 4);
insert into Orders(ticket_number, REGION, STATE, STORE_NUM, A_CODE, SEQ ) 
values('100', 'S', 'F1', '444', 'DLL', 4);
```

O/p -

```
LAST_NAME   TICKET_NUMBER   REGION  STATE   SEQ1    A_CODE
johnson 100 S   F1  1   NULL
```

My understanding is since for same region you have different A_CODE, you need null for A_CODE, but values for all other columns should be the first record.

Hope this helps